# Getting segfault with atoi call

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86, atoi

I have to work with x86 for a homework assignment. I keep getting this segfault for an atoi call, but I'm not sure why it's occurring. This is the code:

```
    addl    $4, %eax
    movl    (%eax), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    atoi
```

Where $eax right before the "call atoi" equals "11". To prove it, this is what I get in gdb right before the call.

```
  x/s $eax
  0xffffd658:    "11"
```

I guess my big question is what should be held in register $eax before the "call atoi" and what would $eax have to hold for the program to then segfault in the "call atoi"?

EDIT: Someone asked for the registers.

```
  (gdb) x/s $eax
  0xffffd658:    "11"
    (gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x2aaaaaa3 in ?? ()
(gdb) inf r
eax            0x0  0
ecx            0x2aaaaaab   715827883
edx            0x0  0
ebx            0x2c3ff4 2899956
esp            0xffffd458   0xffffd458
ebp            0x80484ef    0x80484ef
esi            0x0  0
edi            0x0  0
eip            0x2aaaaaa3   0x2aaaaaa3
eflags         0x10287  [ CF PF SF IF RF ]
cs             0x23 35
ss             0x2b 43
ds             0x2b 43
es             0x2b 43
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x63 99
(gdb)
```

Comment: Can you dump the information of all registers at the time of segfault using gdb command **inf r** command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether your `atoi` function expects the pointer in `%eax` or on the stack. You seem to be undecided about that, given the code segment:

```
movl    %eax, (%esp)
call    atoi
```

If that's supposed to be pushing the address on to the stack, you either need to *really* `push` it (which modifies the stack pointer correctly) or modify the stack pointer yourself (such as with `sub %esp, 4` or something).

The x86 stack pointer points to the *last pushed entry* so that `push` will first decrement the stack pointer then store the value at the new pointer. That means `movl %eax (%esp)` is going to *corrupt* the last pushed entry on the stack rather than place a new value on the stack.

Most people let the CPU handle the stacking of data rather than trying to do it manually, so you're probably looking for:

```
push %eax
```

However, if instead `atoi` expects its argument in `%eax` rather than on the stack, *why* would you write it to the stack? That's *still* going to corrupt whatever was there.

So, the first thing I would do would be choose either (for a pushed value):

```
addl    $4, %eax
movl    (%eax), %eax
push    %eax
call    atoi
```

or (for using `%eax`), just:

```
addl    $4, %eax
movl    (%eax), %eax
call    atoi
```

Comment: This is just a subset of my code, I can post all of it if that would be more helpful

Comment: @Abhishek, I doubt more code will help. It seems likely that you're not pushing the address value correctly. You need to `push` the value so that `esp` gets changed, not just write it to the current `esp` leaving `esp` unchanged..

Comment: I'll give you the check because you led me to the right answer; my error was forgetting that the order of initializing the statement was movl %esp, %ebp instead of what I have up there